# native query and jpa

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jdbc

when using jpa native query
is transaction propagation the only feature of proper JPA we are using ?

I me in my opinio is just like using plain old jdbc pluc jpa transaction propagation

So there's no concept of persistence context ?

Can you validate my ideas , and point me to some me official docs about this ?

EDIT:

> One thing to be careful of with SQL queries that return entities is
>   that the resulting entity instances become managed by the persistence
>   context, just like the results of a JP QL query.

I'm reading the book PRO JPA, and from what I understood
when we use jpa native query to get a set of scalar values (much the same way we   do with jdbc) ther's really no concept of managed entities and persistence   context. 
Things change of course when through native queries we retrieve Entities.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly.  The JPA specification would be what you should reference, but executing a native query through an EntityManager context gives you the same thing a JPQL query would - you can access raw data or have JPA build you managed entities.  If you are going to use it to manage your JDBC connections and statements to execute SQL you are missing the major benefits of JPA.

Comment: so using native query in jpa, aren't we bypassing altogether the persistence context ,?

Comment: in my understanding we do...can you help me to clear up thesebl ideas ?

Comment: As the book states, native queries do not bypass the context.  If you read in raw data, that is what you get back.  But if you have a native query and tell JPA to build you an entity from it (em.createNativeQuery(sqlstring, entity.class)), it will return you managed entities - entities where it tracks any changes and will synchronize those changes with the database.  Just like it would for a JPQL query.  Your question is very broad - why don't you instead focus on what you specificially are looking for and to do?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, there's a big difference in the time it takes to execute JPA native queries and JDBC queries. Probably due to the creation of the persistence context.

Comment: Those costs should be born upfront, just like when creating a datasource of connections, and be one time costs if you are managing the lifecycle efficiently.

Comment: How can you create the persistence context "upfront"?

Comment: You can create it during deployment, and then keep it around.  You don't need to create a persistence unit any time you need to execute a query.  Otherwise, if you are just executing a native query that returns raw data, most providers should give you the similar performance vs executing it through JDBC.

Comment: Sorry, but one persistence context is created for every transaction. You mean I should use a single transaction for all queries?

Comment: The context itself should be lightweight, while the EntityManagerFactory holds the bulk of the JPA processing.  If you are seeing a huge overhead on a native query in JPA vs JDBC, something else is up - such as maintaining a large cache or having JPA build an inefficient object model vs raw data you get from JDBC. Or even factoring in the context deployment costs into the query.